# VBA collections inside dictionary takes forever

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary, optimization, collections

I am connecting to  two CSV files and then trying to do some analysis. The below code runs but does a timeout i.e. Excel just closes in the end. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Should I be writing to a file? any other way to loop the analysis part of the code below.

IMM as list of records not in same order as CEM. Number of records are different as well.

```
    Public Sub CalculateLGDchange(imm, cem)'variant arrays
 Dim ColCount As Long
 Dim RowCount As Long
 Dim fc As Long
 Dim ic As Long
 Dim ir As Long
 Dim nr As Long
 Dim nc As Long
 Dim immdictrwa As New Dictionary
 Dim cemdictrwa As New Dictionary
 Dim immcollgd As New Collection
 Dim cemcollgd As New Collection
 Dim immdictlgd As New Dictionary
 Dim cemdictlgd As New Dictionary
 Dim exceptionlgd As New Dictionary
 Dim key, value
 Dim i As Long

 Set immcollgd = New Collection
 Set immdictlgd = New Dictionary

 ColCount = UBound(imm, 1)
 RowCount = UBound(imm, 2)
 ic = UBound(cem, 1)
 ir = UBound(cem, 2)

 '***********Prepare IMM RWA Dictionary********************'

 For nr = 0 To RowCount
    key = imm(3, nr)
    value = imm(15, nr)
    If immdictrwa.exists(key) Then
       value = value + imm(15, nr)
    Else
        immdictrwa.Add key, value
    End If
Next nr


 '***********Prepare CEM RWA Dictionary********************'

 For nr = 0 To ir
    key = cem(3, nr)
    value = cem(5, nr)
    If cemdictrwa.exists(key) Then
        value = value + cem(15, nr)
    Else
        cemdictrwa.Add key, value
    End If
Next nr


 '***********Prepare IMM LGD Analysis********************'

    For nr = 0 To RowCount 'move through IMM
        For fc = 0 To ir  'move through CEM
                If StrComp(imm(3, nr), cem(3, fc)) = 0 Then 'compare gids
                     immcollgd.Add imm(14, nr)
                     immcollgd.Add cem(14, nr)
                     If immcollgd.Item(1) > immcollgd.Item(2) Then
                         immcollgd.Add "IMM LGD IS GREATER"
                     ElseIf immcollgd.Item(1) = immcollgd.Item(2) Then
                         immcollgd.Add "IMM LGD NOT CHANGED"
                     ElseIf immcollgd.Item(2) <> 0.45 And immcollgd.Item(1) = 0.45 Then
                        immcollgd.Add "PARENT LGD FALLBACK"
                     ElseIf immcollgd.Item(2) = 0.45 And immcollgd.Item(1) = 0.45 Then
                        immcollgd.Add "CHILD LGD FALLBACK"
                     ElseIf immcollgd.Item(2) < immcollgd.Item(1) Then
                        immcollgd.Add "CHILD LGD SMALLER"
                     Else
                        immcollgd.Add "INVESTIGATE"
                     End If
                        key = imm(3, nr)
                            If immdictlgd.exists(key) Then
                                If immdictlgd(key).Item(1) = imm(14, nr) Then
                                'do nothing
                                Else
                                exceptionlgd.Add imm(3, nr), imm(14, nr)
                                End If
                            Else
                                immdictlgd.Add imm(3, nr), immcollgd
                            End If
                Set immcollgd = New Collection
                Else
                End If

        Next fc
    Next nr
End Sub
```

Comment: How large are the files?

Comment: 192 MB each of them

Comment: It's possible that large nested loop in "Prepare IMM LGD Analysis" is what's killing your performance.  You could consider creating a Dictionary-based row lookup for the `cem` array(gid as key and an array of row numbers as value) and use that in place of the inner loop - should be faster.  Also worth performing some timings on the other sections to see where the slowness really is.  If you use smaller files as input you will still get meaningful numbers...